# in-memory table quota reached in error

Tags: sql-server-2016, memory-optimized-tables

**Edit 1:**
From article posted by first answer > this:

> Additionally, if you are using memory optimized table in the context of table valued parameters repeatedly, you may encounter this error even you use them in a separate batch and memory gets released.  We are looking to address this issue in future cumulative updates.  For now, you either need to use enterprise edition or periodically restart SQL or offline/online the database.

I use in-memory table valued parameters continually.  However as a troubleshooting step, I re-deployed the solution and removed all memory optimization.  I still received this error message.  After restarting the service the message is gone and I'm able to use in-memory tables once again.

**Original Post:**

I'm receiving this message (Sql Server Standard 2016 sp1 on VM):

> Could not perform the operation because the database has reached its quota for in-memory tables.

However, in-memory table usage is zero as shown here.  Any idea how to recover from this state or even start to investigate what is going on?

[image]

Comment: Were you performing any operation/running any query when you got this error message? Where did you get this message? Was there any other message in the errorlog at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

You may be running into this:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/psssql/2017/06/07/you-may-see-out-of-user-memory-quota-message-in-errorlog-when-you-use-in-memory-oltp-feature/